# Open file / content of other app into my own iOS app, when my app was in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a mobile clipper.
When in a galery app, I want to be able to send a picture to my app.
When in the browser, I want to be able to send the current url to my app.

**Note**: I'm already aware that I should add a `CFBundleDocumentTypes` to the plist file so that my app appears in the list of apps to which I can send data (see also
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290))

So when the "share" action is triggered while my app is not started, I can listen to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then extract the data from the launch options.

But when my app is already started and is in background, and I share an image or an url to it, obviously the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will not trigger so I won't be able to get a dictionnary to which I can get my data.

See approved comment in original answer:

> it should be noted that -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in the app delegate is only called if your app was not backgrounded when it's opened to handle a file.

So, how can I handle both cases: when my app was in background and is made active, and when my app was simply started?

Sorry if this question is dumb as I'm not a iOS dev at all and trying to do my first cordova plugin.

My app should be compatible with at least iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below application delegate method

**For IOS 9 and later**

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options

**Below IOS 9**

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication
>     annotation:(id)annotation

Comment: thanks it seems nice, but does seem to be new in iOS 9 and I need support for iOS 7

Comment: thanks. By the way is there a way to liste for a NSNotification? or should it absolutly be in the delegate?

Comment: No i don't see any notification key for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need support iOS 7:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;`

Answer (score 1):

The process is described in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

> An app that has its own custom URL scheme must be able to handle URLs
>   passed to it. All URLs are passed to your app delegate, either at
>   launch time or while your app is running or in the background. To
>   handle incoming URLs, your delegate should implement the following
>   methods:
>
> - Use the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and
>     `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods to retrieve
>     information about the URL and decide whether you want to open it. If
>     either method returns NO, your app’s URL handling code is not called.
> - Use the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method to
>     open the file.

It is this second method that will be invoked if your app is running in the background

Comment: thanks for the official doc link. My app does not have a custom url scheme but I guess it's still valid